# SSI analog for XUL

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

Is there a way to split a huge `xul` file into small `xul` files like we can do it using SSI (shtml), tpl, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mozilla uses the C++ preprocessor for that, it runs during build before the XUL file is packaged. See for example [browser.xul](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/eb7d13ddeeaf/browser/base/content/browser.xul) (look for `#include`).

If you want to have this behavior at runtime however (along with the unavoidable performance degradation) you have the choice between [XUL Overlays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Overlays) and [XBL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/Introduction_to_XBL). Which one to choose depends on your goal. If you merely want to specify the contents of a particular tag in a different file then overlays are the way to go. If you need to generate multiple tags with the same or similar contents then you would use XBL.

Comment: I've just tried to use an overlay, but it doesn't seem to work. I'd created new `xul` file with `xml` and `overlay` tags and added `<?xul-overlay href="chrome://component/content/myNewXUL.xul"?>` into an existing `xul` file. Firefox shows no errors and no content.

Comment: @DanielJF: If you have problems making overlays work you probably want to create a new question showing the actual code you tried. Just to make sure you didn't misunderstand the article: overlays extend elements already present in the original document. You need to define an element with the same ID in your overlay or Firefox won't know where to put your content.

Comment: I followed [this tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/Overlays) and it works now. Thanks!